# Inserting data into table via Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel table and I am trying to automate the deletion of data and insertion of data into an excel table.

I am using this VBA code to remove my data from my table

```
Sub Macro2()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Report").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Report").HeaderRowRange.Select
    'Remove the filters if one exists.
    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
    Selection.AutoFilter
    End If

    With Worksheets("Report").ListObjects("Engagement_report")
        .DataBodyRange.Offset(1).Resize(.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count - 1, .DataBodyRange.Columns.Count).Rows.Delete
        .DataBodyRange.Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
    End With

End Sub
```

However, when i try to insert data(about 11 000 rows) into the same table it is very slow and my excel crashes. I am not sure if its because the resize function i does deletes all rows and hence when i insert data again, it is redoing the range and hence its slow.

Does anyone have any suggestions to help in this?

Appreciate your help

Comment: Do you must use `Delete` ? Is using `ClearContents` not enough ? You can also get rid of the  multi `Select` in the begining

Comment: What other things do you have on that worksheet? Consider moving whatever else you have to another sheet and keep a dedicated worksheet just for your 11K rows, not using a ListObject.

Comment: Hi @Variatus, I have a formulas on this particular sheet and I converted this whole data to a table range as I am using these formulas to evaluate different business conditions and criteria.

Comment: Do table formulas extend if calculation is set to manual?  If so, try setting manual calculation before you insert (paste?) the data then force recalculation after.

Comment: Surely, if you delete the cells which your formulas refer to the formulas can't return the expected results thereafter. If the intention is to replace the values the formulas reference then @Shai Rado should be correct in suggesting that you `ClearContents` rather than `Delete`. Still, the better layout would be for the data not to be on the same sheet as the evaluations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Sub addDataToTable(ByVal strTableName As String, _  
   ByVal strData As String, ByVal col As Integer)

 ActiveSheet.Table(strTableName).Select
 If strTableName.Rows.Count = 1 Then
     strTableName(Row, col).Value = strData
 Else
     strTable(LastRow, col).Value = strData
 End If
End Sub
```

NB : I think this will be helpful to you.

Comment: It's my pleasure Adrian,, please keep asking ☺

Answer (score 0):

This sample code will help you to insert multiple rows.

```
Sub InsrtRw2()
Dim c As Range, fst As Range, c2 As Range

Set c = Cells.Find("Test", MatchCase:=False, _
lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)


If Not c Is Nothing Then
c(2).EntireRow.Resize(10).Insert

Set fst = c

again:

Set c2 = Cells.FindNext(c)

If Not c2 Is Nothing Then

If c2.Address <> c.Address _
And c2.Address <> fst.Address Then

c2(2).EntireRow.Resize(10).Insert

Set c = c2

GoTo again

End If
End If
End If

End Sub
```